# Why is GPU accelerated node much slower than CPU node for training a random forest model on databricks?

Tags: random-forest, pyspark

I have a dataset about 5 million rows with 14 features and a binary target. I decided to train a pyspark random forest classifier on Databricks. The CPU cluster I created contains 2 c4.8xlarge workers (60GB, 36core) and 1 r4.xlarge (31GB, 4core) driver. The GPU cluster I created contains 3 g4dn.4xlarge (64GB, 16cores) nodes, 2 as workers and 1 as driver. The hourly costs are very similar. I assumed that GPU cluster would outperform since random forest is an algorithm born for parallel computing, while the result kinda shocked me that the GPU cluster trained the model near 5 times slower than the CPU cluster. Is there anything I misunderstood about GPU acceleration or is it just not used for pyspark.ml modules.

Comment: I'm no expert about this, but my understanding is that a GPU is relevant for parallelizing the same kind of calculations, like linear algebra equations. Random forests can be trained efficiently with distributed tasks, but each computation on one core is different (independent) from the one on the next core. So my guess would be that this is what makes a GPU not so good for RF.